# Promise rejected or fulfilled confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, promise

I have a promise function

```
create(data) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const datetime = Date.parse(new Date());
            data.createdAt = datetime;
            data.updatedAt = datetime;
            this._db.collection(this._table).insertOne(data, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    this._logger.error(err);
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(data);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

And write unit test for it

```
it('should reject insertion', () => {
    const promise = Agent.create(data).then(() => (Agent.create(data)));
    return expect(promise).to.be.rejected;
});
```

This assertion passes. But if the unit test is:

```
it('should reject insertion', () => {
    const promise = Agent.create(data).then(Agent.create(data));
    return expect(promise).to.be.rejected;
});
```

It fails. The error is `AssertionError: expected promise to be rejected but it was fulfilled with { Object (_id, role, ...) }`

Where is the difference between these two practices? I haven't gotten it.

Comment: Are you asking what the difference between `() => Agent.create(data)` and `Agent.create(data)` is?

Comment: the difference is the difference between passing a function to `.then` (which is what .then expects), and passing in the result of a function (in this case a Promise) to `.then` ... .then ignores any non-function argument passed to it and the resulting promise returned by `.then` takes on the value of the preceding promise - which, of course is a resolved, not a rejected, promise

Comment: @JaromandaX As I perceive, will they yield the same results (rejected) if I change the second to
`Agent.create(data).then(Agent.create(data).catch...)`
or
`Agent.create(data).then(Agent.create(data)).catch`

Comment: no, the argument to `.then` needs to be a function, not the result of calling a function

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks a lot. I've got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many in comments have indicated, You're passing a function in the first case and the return value in the other case, which is a promise. That's the reason you're seeing the differences in outcomes.

Comment: As I perceive, will they yield the same results (rejected) if I change the second to
`Agent.create(data).then(Agent.create(data).catch...)`
or
`Agent.create(data).then(Agent.create(data)).catch`

Comment: Not the best way to chain promises. Look here: https://html5hive.org/how-to-chain-javascript-promises/